# git garbage-size out of control, need understanding

Tags: git, garbage-collection, dvcs, unreal-engine4

we are using git as our DVCS for a very large project (yes, I know git it's not always pointed at as the best for these situations), and there's something I don't quite understand about my repo.

This is my count-objects output:

```
count: 53
size: 1.57 MiB
in-pack: 26444
packs: 2
size-pack: 42.49 GiB
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 8
size-garbage: 32.22 GiB
```

as you can see the size is less than 2Mb, the size-pack is 43Gb (what is this, exactly?), but the size-garbage is 32Gb! What is that? Can I remove it? How?

I tried many options found on the internet with very poor understanding of what they do on a separate repository with basically no gains or major changes. Like:

```
git reflog expire --all --expire=now
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
git gc
git repack -a -d --depth=250 --window=250
```

Answer (score 3):

```
git reflog expire --all --expire=now
```

You typically don't want to use this as an end user, but it can be useful if you introduced a massive amount of data ended up pulling it out of the branch (as in resetting back to a previous commit, and generating a new commit without the data).  In this case, you'd still have an active reference to the data in the reflog, and git would keep the objects around until they expired.

```
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

Avoid the `--aggressive` option.  It does way too much work for far too little gain, in my experience.  However, the variant `git gc --prune=now` is *probably* what you want.  This will remove any unreferenced data.  Generally, Git keeps unreferenced data around for a couple of weeks, but that can add up pretty quickly.  Also, it will repack the repository, which can save quite a bit of space as compared to loose objects (loose objects are not compressed).

```
git gc
```

This form of `git gc` can be useful too.  It will still prune, but using the default time frame instead.  Anything that is younger than the default will be left as a loose object, so if you're intent on improving disk space, I would not recommend this form.

```
git repack -a -d --depth=250 --window=250
```

This one has been out there a while, but generally applied wrongly.  This is only really helpful if you've converted your repository from another version control system, and the conversion process didn't choose good parents for packing.  It's also really expensive to compute and will take a long time to finish.  In repositories that were converted with poor delta choices, it can make a *huge* difference.  But it's not likely what you are looking for.

```
count: 53
size: 1.57 MiB
in-pack: 26444
packs: 2
size-pack: 42.49 GiB
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 8
size-garbage: 32.22 GiB
```

> as you can see the size is less than 2Mb, the size-pack is 43Gb (what is this, exactly?), but the size-garbage is 32Gb! What is that? Can I remove it? How?

`size` refers to the loose objects on disk that are currently referenced.  This could be through the reflog, branches, remotes, etc.  The `size-garbage` field is the interesting one.  This is data that is currently *unreferenced* and available for garbage collection.  `git gc` would remove it right now, as long as it's more than 2 weeks old.  `git gc --prune=now` would remove it despite it's age.

So, in the end, it's likely `git gc --prune=now` that you want to run on the repository.

Comment: Uhm... Apparently, not really. I've run a `git gc --prune=now`, but the result is this:

     `count: 0
     size: 0 bytes
     in-pack: 26728
     packs: 1
     size-pack: 42.53 GiB
     prune-packable: 0
     garbage: 12
     size-garbage: 117.17 GiB`

Comment: That makes no sense.  Is the repository actively being accessed by others?  It smells like something else is going on here.

Comment: well, people do commit, push and pull stuff, but I'm the only one that manages it on the server side...

Comment: I can confirm each time I use `git gc --prune=now` the size-garbage increases. Overnight it went to `159.70 GiB`

Comment: Can you provide the output of `ls .git/objects/pack`?  Or if it's a bare repository, `ls objects/pack`?  How active is the repository?  I'm just curious if git is doing something to leave the pack file around if it's actively being accessed by others (IIRC, it does something like that under the hood, just to make sure things don't accidentally disappear).  In my local repositories, `git gc --prune=now` always leaves 0 garbage.  Perhaps trying it without it being accessed by others is a start.  Can you copy the repo elsewhere and try it offline?

Comment: Last time (the one that bumped the garbage to 159GiB) was 100% not being accessed by others.

the output of `ls objects/pack` is:  
  
`pack-b7625bea906abfdda6670e73132ced05a5e03f43.idx  
pack-b7625bea906abfdda6670e73132ced05a5e03f43.pack`

Comment: Okay, so no `.bitmap` files are hanging around.  How would you feel about reporting this on the Git user's mailing list?  There are several people who may have more insight as to what is happening.  BTW, what version of Git are you running?